# Adding Images to a demo app. Code taken from tutorial

Tags: android, xml, image

I am learning how to use the horizontal scroll feature in Android. I came across this tutorial [by ysamlan](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager) and used it as a demo to start off learning. What I want to know is how can I add a new ImageView as there is already a setContentView in the class. For adding new images to the demo it says so:

```
 /*
     * Note that you can also define your own views directly in a resource XML, too by using:
     * <com.ur.demo.pack
     *     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     *     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     *     android:id="@+id/real_view_switcher">
     *     <!-- your views here -->
     * </com.ur.demo.pack>
     */
```

I am confused as to which xml file am I supposed to declare the images. Below is the entire code for the particular class. Kindly help me.

```
package ur.demo.pack;


public class HorizontalPagerDemo extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the view switcher
    HorizontalPager realViewSwitcher = new HorizontalPager(getApplicationContext());

    // Add some views to it
   final int[] backgroundColors =
            { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.WHITE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DKGRAY, Color.LTGRAY };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
        textView.setTextSize(100);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColors[i]);
        realViewSwitcher.addView(textView);
    }

    // set as content view

    setContentView(realViewSwitcher);

    // Yeah, it really is as simple as this :-)

    /*
     * Note that you can also define your own views directly in a resource XML, too by using:
     * <com.ur.demo.pack
     *     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     *     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     *     android:id="@+id/real_view_switcher">
     *     <!-- your views here -->
     * </com.ur.demo.pack>
     */

    // OPTIONAL: listen for screen changes
    realViewSwitcher.setOnScreenSwitchListener(onScreenSwitchListener);
}

private final HorizontalPager.OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener =
        new HorizontalPager.OnScreenSwitchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScreenSwitched(final int screen) {
                Log.d("HorizontalPager", "switched to screen: " + screen);
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use this code

```
final int[] images = {R.drawable.1, R.drawable.2,};
  for(int i=0; i<images.length; i++){
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
     imageView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImages[i]);
     realViewSwitcher.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

What the code does is define all the views in the code and place them in one container layout (HorizontalPager). Then it sets the layout to be displayed in the activity. This is, however, less frequent in the Android development. I am not quite sure I get it correctly, maybe you already have some experience with Android, but the more usual way of defining layouts is via using the layout subfolder of res/. You define all your views using xml and custom Android tags and then when you build you can access the layout files via R.layout., thus setting them as the content of activity. Here goes one example layout taken from the Android tutorials:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you place it in custom_layout.xml you access it and set it to your activity like that:

```
setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);
```

There is a special tag for ImageView too. So if I get it correctly the suggestion is that you can add the image view in the custom_layout.xml. On the other hand I can confirm that you can also keep on constructing the layouts entirely in-code and use

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
imageView.setResourceContent(R.drawable.my_png);
```

Comment: ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
imageView.setResourceContent(R.drawable.my_png);
This helped me thanks Boris.